# PHP MYSQL запрос. Двойной UPDATE, используя одинаковые значения

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно обновить таблицу `chats`, поле `lastupdate = time()`, где `WHERE id = $id;`

Так же мне нужно обновить таблицу `members`, поле `lastvisit = time()`, где `WHERE chatid = $id;`

То  есть два запроса, которые используют одни и те же переменные. Так вот складывается вопрос, возможно ли это сделать по умному одним UPDATE? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2):

Вам повезло, MySQL практически единственная СУБД, в которой это возможно:

```
update chats A
  join members B on A.id=B.chatid
   set A.lastupdate=NOW(), B.lastvisit=NOW()
 where A.id=$id
```

И передавать time() из php в запрос не обязательно, MySQL функция `NOW()` возвращает текущее время (в формате datetime, надеюсь у вас время в БД хранится именно в этом типе данных).

Правда возникает вопрос у структуре вашей БД. Судя по названиям lastvisit это время последнего посещения конкретным member'ом чата. Зачем обновлять время во всех member'ах данного чата одновременно, мне представить сложно. И если вы всегда обновляете и то и другое время, возникает вопрос, а действительно ли вам нужны два поля с временем обновления и в chats и в members